# Pip3 installation issues

Tags: python, ios, terminal, pip

I have been having many problems with selenium which I download through pip. On Sublime I would get and error saying there is no module named selenium when I did in fact have it installed. Now I have tried to delete every file so I could start fresh but I am running into new problems. I deleted Homebrew files, selenium files, and python files. When I reinstalled Homebrew and then python it said that python had already existed. Then when I tried to use the pip3 command I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in `<module>`
>       from pip._internal.main import main
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Mac is a nightmare. I have run in to problem after problem and once I fix one there is always another.

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have pip installed.

try

```
easy_install pip
```

or try

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

for mac try below:

```
curl 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' > get-pip.py && sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I did so and got this error: error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-28346.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

See the rest below:

Comment: Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: I now got this error: python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @Yuu this is my pip3 problem

Comment: @DylanSiegeltry the new one I have suggested. Hope that works.

Comment: I tried that and I realized it was running python 2.7. Even though I have Python 3 installed it seems to be refusing to run it. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled python 3 through homebrew.

Comment: can you provide the full trace now ?

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Comment: WARNING: The directory '/Users/dylansiegel/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/dylansiegel/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: Even though I have python 3 install on home-brew for some reason it is always referring to python 2.7

Comment: I got this: /usr/bin/python

Comment: I typed it into terminal and all I got was the option to type help or a couple other what seemed to be insignificant things.

Comment: I just checked again and I believe that what I have to do is make the version of python on homebrew the default, but I do not now how to do that.

Comment: try this `brew link --overwrite python`

Comment: I got this: Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: Just to give you some insight - I wanted to reinstall everything because it was not working. Because I am inexperienced I went into spotlight search, searched things like pip and python, and dragged this files into the trash. I think I permanently deleted files I should not have causing my fresh installations to not function correctly. I have decided to give up on using my mac and I have switched to doing my project through cmd. I hope there is not too much of a difference between cmd and terminal and i'll be able to troubleshoot my problems, if any, by searching it on the internet.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and I will keep you posted and comment if I need help.

Comment: In terminal I would use the vi command to create a file in a file: `vi bot.py` how could I do this on cmd?